just_audio_background lost initial styles
I developed an audio app that applies some styles to the Android status bar as well as the navigatorbar. I also limit the rotation of the app, only for the portal. I also use just_audio_background.
Just_audio_background allows me to "close" the application, and the audio plays in the background, so the just_audio miniplayer is active, and when I click on it, as it should, it opens my application again. The problem is that, when the app opens, the styles defined for statusBar, navigatorBar and rotation are lost.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
  ]);

  try {
    await JustAudioBackground.init(
      androidNotificationChannelId: 'com.app.bg_demo.channel.audio',
      androidNotificationChannelName: 'Audio playback',
      androidNotificationOngoing: true,
    );

   

    runApp(const MyApp());
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint('Erro durante a inicialização: $e');
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      lazy: false,
      create: (_) => HinarioProvider(),
      child: const MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        showPerformanceOverlay: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: AppWidget(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`

